# Can you synthesize phenol from salicyladehyde?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry

Can you synthesize phenol from salicyladehyde? Well for starters I know that salicyladehyde can be obtained from phenol through Reimer–Tiemann reaction but I was wondering if the reverse was possible.

Comment: Oxidation and decarboxylation.  But this is an expensive way to make phenol.

Comment: An even more expensive way: stoichiometric rhodium decarbonylation. Apparently, though, [that is now possible catalytically](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja710270j).

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to convert salicylaldehyde into phenol in a two-step process. Firstly, salicylaldehyde is oxidized to salicylic acid with a standard reagent like $\ce{KMnO4}$ (see the answers to [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5006/can-salicylic-acid-be-synthesized-from-salicylaldehyde)).

In the second step, salicylic acid is thermally decarboxylated to phenol in a simple distillation apparatus. Solid salicylic acid is strongly heated in a round-bottom flask equipped with a short path distillation head with thermometer. Heating is maintained to keep a reasonable distillation rate of the desired product (phenol passes over at a temperature range from 145 to 165 °C). Most by-products of the reaction, like phenyl salicylate, have higher boiling points and remain in the residue. The crude product can finally be purified by vacuum distillation, for example, at a pressure of 30 Torr and a temperature range of 85 - 90 °C ([reference](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=27617)).